# why is sizeof() returning 4 bytes rather than 2 bytes of short int?

Tags: c

To print the size of the variables using sizeof()

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a = 10,b = 20; 
    short int c;
    short int d = sizeof(c = a+b);
    int e = sizeof(c*d); //e holds the value of 4 rather than 2
    double f = sizeof(e*f);
    printf("d:%d\ne:%d\nf:%lf\n",d,e,f);
}
```

Why is sizeof() returning the size of int rather than short int which is meant to be 2 bytes?

Comment: See also: [why sizeof(short + short) has different size than sizeof(short)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24610737/253056)

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
sizeof(c = a+b);
```

doesn't measure the size of variable `c` but the size of the value computed from expression `c = a+b`. It is the value of `a+b` that is assigned to `c` but it is also the value of the entire expression.

The integral values whose storage type is smaller than `int` that appear in an arithmetic expression are promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) for the computation. The storage type of the result of the arithmetic expression is `int`. This is not affected that the fact that you store it in a `short int` variable. Hence the value returned by `sizeof()`.

The same for `sizeof(c*d)`.